# Modify an image using caman and then upload it to firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, camanjs

Here is my problem. I want to modify an image using caman and then upload it to firebase. That's my code

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import firebase from 'firebase';

declare var Caman: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-filtri',
  templateUrl: 'filtri.html'
})
export class FiltriPage {

fotoModificata: any;
public fotoScelta;
itemRef : firebase.database.Reference = firebase.database().ref('/matrimonio1');
firestore = firebase.storage();
alertCtrl: AlertController;
imgsource: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, alertCtrl: AlertController,   public zone: NgZone,
) {

    this.alertCtrl = alertCtrl;
    this.fotoScelta = navParams.get("foto");
  }

  addFilter(){

       Caman("#image", function(){
         this.brightness(5);
         this.render(function () {
         var fotoModificata = this.toBase64();

   });

 });

}


upload() {


    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    const filename = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    const imageRef = storageRef.child(`images/${filename}.jpg`);

    imageRef.putString(this.fotoModificata, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL).then((snapshot)=> {

// il codice sotto prende l'url della foto appena caricata
         this.firestore.ref().child(`images/${filename}.jpg`).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
           this.zone.run(() => {
             this.imgsource = url;

// carica l'url in firebase.database
      let newPostRef = this.itemRef.push();
          newPostRef.set({
            "nome" : " ",
            "url" : url
          });


            })
         });

         this.showSuccesfulUploadAlert();


       }, (err) => { });

  }

  showSuccesfulUploadAlert() {

      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Caricata!',
        subTitle: 'La foto è stata caricata!',
        buttons: ['OK']
      });
      alert.present();

      this.fotoModificata = "";

  }

}
```

I know for sure that the upload() function works. Ho can I export the var fotoModificata from the addFilter function to be used in upload() ? If I use console.log immediately after the var declaration i can see in console the base64 string of my image but if I log in console somewhere else I've and undefined. How can I solve?

Comment: I guess all you need is to add to change this line: var fotoModificata = this.toBase64(); to be this.fotoModificata = this.toBase64(); but to do that you need to ensure "this" is pointing to the whoel component of yours. For that I would use arrow function: Caman("#image", () => { ... }

Comment: try and let me know if it helps:) I am learning as well but I think that should work for you.

Comment: If I use that I’ve an errore while compiling that says that brightness and render are not properties of filtripage

Comment: I tried this: 'addFilter(){

       Caman("#image", function () {
         this.brightness(5);
         this.render( () => {
         this.fotoModificata = this.toBase64();

   });

 });

}'

But when I call upload() I've ERROR Error: [object Object]

Comment: wait a sec:) i think I know what is wrong - disregard my previous comment. I will post working code in 3 mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this feels like all you need is to pass result of addFilter function (currently stored in var fotoModificata) to global var (fotoModificata).

I would do this below:

```
addFilter() {

    // save scope of global "this" here:
    let scope = this;

    Caman("#image", function(){
      this.brightness(5);
      this.render(function() {
      // use the scope as a pointer to the global scope to assign the value:
      scope.fotoModificata = this.toBase64();
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Still have ERROR Error: [object Object] in console calling upload() with a button from html. Also if I write after this.fotoModificata = temp; console.log(this.fotoModificata); I retrieve an undefined in console so I think that the value of temp is still somehow jailed in Caman function.

Comment: OK I will copy your code and see it to work. Did you manage to successfully log to console base64 from you code?

Comment: Basically - let me know what do you get if ytou log -> var fotoModificata in the addFilter funciton

Comment: I think my example is wrong now as the var temp never "makes it" to the function...

Comment: BTW did you check if render function is sync or async? it can be that it needs async handling. This would explain why the temp is undefined...

Comment: I can console base64 string only if I call it immediatly after tobase64(). How can I check sync or async?

Comment: It seems that render is async due to this https://github.com/meltingice/CamanJS/wiki/About-the-block-renderer

Comment: Yes makes sense. Ok then you need to use async/await in this function or use promise and once resolved call the function that needs base64 string. Do you have examples with promises?

Comment: Can you share how these functions are called in ui?

Comment: '<ion-content padding>
  <img id='image' class="foto" src={{fotoScelta}} />
  <button ion-button (click)="addFilter()">Filtro</button>
  <button ion-button (click)="upload()">Ok</button>
</ion-content>'
That's my code. Can you write me a promise example? By the way you are really really kind. thank you so much to help me

Comment: I will post in in 2 hours. But looking at ui it seems like it could be something else as buttons are separate.

Comment: Thanks again. I would like to use a button for apply filter and another one for upload final image

Comment: Hey yo, so I am willing to help but I can't install all the dependencies from your project;/ can you help me with the following: if you console log the var as in the snippet below : addFilter(){

      Caman("#image", function(){
        this.brightness(5);
        this.render(function () {
        var fotoModificata = this.toBase64();
        console.log(fotoModificata)  
      });

    });

  } what is the value of the var that console gives you - is it base64 string?

Comment: Yes it is the string in base64

Comment: Sorry I am kind of doing it in blind mode;/ since your buttons are separate, it should not be an async issue here. But I am curious as to why the base64 value is not getting assigned to the fotoModificata. Try this below and see what console.log(temp) gives you in console?: addFilter(){

      let temp = Caman("#image", function(){
        this.brightness(5);
        this.render(function() {
        return this.toBase64();
      });

      // console.log(temp)

      this.fotoModificata = temp

    });

  }

Comment: I think I know why in my asnwers example the value is not getting assigned: since base64 string is still a string - the moment we do this.fotoModificata = temp; in my answer's snippet - we just assign "undefined" to it. And once later on "temp" gets actual base64 string - there is never a reassignment. You can test my theory by making temp = "test" and then seeing what my answer's snippet gives you in the console (it should give you "test")

Comment: Can you try this trick now: addFilter(){

      let scope = this;

      Caman("#image", function(){
          this.brightness(5);
          this.render(function() {
          scope.fotoModificata = this.toBase64();
        });

      });

  }

Comment: Oh Man!!! It works!!! You saved me!!! If you answer with this solution I'll mark as solved!!! Thanks so much

Comment: ;)) all good i was also puzzled and glad it worked! The answer is updated!